# How to handle multiple redirects to different origins in Cypress

Tags: redirect, cypress, cross-domain, cypress-origin

I need to visit a URL that redirects twice to different origins. e.g:

> domain-to-visit.com -> redirect1.com -> final-domain.com

This code below works for a single redirect:

```js
cy.origin('redirect1.com') => {
  cy.visit('domain-to-visit.com');
});
```

But I need to support more than one redirect.

My reflex is to want to wrap the above code in another `cy.origin` but that is not supported yet.

How can I visit `domain-to-visit.com` and allow it to redirect to multiple origins in Cypress?

Answer (score 5):

Just write an origin command for any redirect URL you are interested in testing something on.

If you have `domain-to-visit.com -> redirect1.com -> final-domain.com` and want to take action in `final-domain.com`, your code would be

```js
cy.visit('domain-to-visit.com');

// you can ignore the intermediate domain "redirect1.com"

cy.origin('final-domain.com') => {
  cy.get(...).should(...)           // test this page
})
```

---

#### Testing the intermediate page

If you want to also test something on `redirect1.com`, just add another `cy.origin()`, not nested but sequentially.

This only makes sense if the web page needs an action to go to the final page, as far as I can see.

```js
cy.visit('domain-to-visit.com');

cy.origin('redirect1.com') => {
  cy.get(...).should(...)           // test this page
  cy.get('a[href="..."]').click()   // redirect onwards
})

cy.origin('final-domain.com') => {
  cy.get(...).should(...)           // test this page
})
```

---

#### A reproducible example

**base-page.html**

Uses HTML redirect in `<meta>` tag

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/redirect1.html'" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Base page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Served on port 3000:

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' })
  fs.createReadStream('html/base-page.html').pipe(res)
})
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

**redirect1.html**

Uses javascript redirect on button click.

Served on port 5500:

```js
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Redirect 1</h1>
    <button onclick="redirect()">Redirect</button>
    <script>
      function redirect() {
        window.location = "https://example.com"
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Test**

```js
cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
cy.get('h1').contains('Base page')                                // passes

cy.origin('http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/redirect1.html', () => {
  cy.get('h1').contains('Redirect 1')                             // passes
  cy.get('button').contains('Redirect').click()
})  

cy.origin('https://example.com', () => {
  cy.get('h1').contains('Example Domain')                         // passes
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

But actually after trying your solution I realized there was more to my problem than the redirects.

The part I didn’t mention is that I need to visit another url before.
In other words I need something like the following to work:


```cy.visit(‘original-domai.com’);
cy.visit(‘domain-to-visit.com’);
```


Normally I could wrap the second visit in a cy.origin and it would work.
However, because it redirects multiple times, `cy.origin` doesn't seem to work.
Is there a way to make the above work given the second domain has two redirects?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you need to visit, since the redirect has already navigated?

Comment: `original-domain.com` is the site I'm really testing.
`domain-to-visit.com` is in an iframe but i've had issues interacting with it so I opted to just visit it directly.
This solution has worked for me in the past with other iframe urls, but lately I've had to test one that redirects twice and I haven't found a way for Cypress to allow me to do that.